# PHP 7.3 is running on Mac but not installed anywhere

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

When I check `brew services list` I see that the only PHP version running is 7.2.

When I do `php -v` I'm shown:

```
WARNING: PHP is not recommended
PHP is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
Future versions of macOS will not include PHP.
PHP 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS) (cli) (built: May  8 2021 09:40:37) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.24, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

I ran `locate php` and no instances of PHP 7.3 turn up for me to remove. Only directories for 7.2 show up.

If I try `brew remove php` or `brew remove php@7.3` then nothing happens.

How do I locate this phantom PHP version and completely remove it from my computer?

Comment: What does `type php` show?

Comment: `php is /usr/bin/php`

Comment: I don't think `brew` installs in `/usr/bin`, so that's the version that comes with MacOS.

Comment: exporting the correct path in the bash profile fixed this